# Linkedlist Remove Duplicates without buffer

Tags: python, linked-list

I am trying to implement an algorithm to remove duplicates from a linkedlist but my algorithm freeze when it comes to check if the current node has data equal with the next one.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

class LinkedList:
   def __init__(self, head = None):
      self.head = head

   def add(self, item):
      newNode = Node(item, self.head)
      self.head = newNode

   def printit(self):
      current = self.head
      while current is not None:
         print(current.data)
         current = current.next

   def removeDuplicates(self):
      current = self.head
      while current != None:
         runner = current
         while runner.next != None:
            if runner.next.data == current.data:
               runner.next = current.next.next
            else:
               runner = current.next
         current = current.next




mylist = LinkedList()

mylist.add(31)
mylist.add(77)
mylist.add(31)
mylist.add(22)
mylist.add(22)
mylist.add(22)

mylist.printit()
mylist.removeDuplicates()
mylist.printit()
```

It is maybe really silly, but I can't spot it right now, any ideas?

Comment: `next` is a python keyword. Use some other name to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your while loop:

```
runner = current.next
```

should be

```
runner = runner.next
```

otherwise it just keeps taking the same `current.next` on each iteration, since it never changes `current` in the loop. Same fix a couple of lines earlier.

Comment: You were right! Ty. Actually I was confused, I created the runner to avoid changing the pointer of the outer loop and then in my head was the idea of the "current".

Comment: It's always easier to see this stuff with a fresh pair of eyes. It's worth single-stepping through in a debugger, especially if you can't get someone to review your code, to see where reality and your expectations part company.

Comment: `runner.next = current.next.next` should also be `runner.next = runner.next.next`.